# Include link created with CONCATENATE from one cell into IMPORTHTML formula in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am generating a link combining two values from two cells C2 and D2 using CONCATENATE formula in cell B2. Then I want to include generated link into another formula =IMPORTHTML("URL"; "table"; 3 ) in A2 cell. A simple pointing of a cell B2 in field "URL" in the abovementioned formula did not give a good result. Please help fix syntax. [image: Screen is attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
"B2"
```

Use

```
B2
```

The formula will be

```
=IMPORTHTML(B2;"table";3)
```